# JAVA unmarshal SAML attributes with no type

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, saml, xml-namespaces

Client sends SAML Assertion with no type in attribute values:

```
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute Name="attrName">
            <saml:AttributeValue>val</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
```

To my knowledge this is not forbidden according to SAML standard.

My JAVA implementation use JAXB Unmarshaller to procces the assertion.
When extracting the attribute value i get :

```
saml:AttributeValue: null
```

Are there other solutions for this, without forcing the client to add the type?

Comment: To unmarshal this with JAXB, you need a class which is appropriately mapped.

Comment: lexicore can you clarify what is that class or give an example ?

Comment: No, sorry, don't want to invest the effort. Read just any JAXB tutorial, you'll get a clue.

Comment: You XML is invalid. It starts with a closing tag